# INSERT/UPDATE with CONFLICT with Autoincrement Postgres

Tags: postgresql

I have an `answers` table, which has `answers.id`, `answers.question_id`, `answers.value` and `answers.report_id`

`answers.id` is autoincremented upon regular insert.

`answers.question_id` holds a value between 1 and 10 because there are 10 questions but are not unique to the table and depend on a `report_id` column.

`answers.report_id` is used to reference a report in a separate table.

**What I want to achieve** is to insert a new record if there is no conflicting `questions_id` for the particular `report_id`. If there is a conflict, update the record with the new `value`

So far I've read about UPSERT

**I tried the following query**

```
INSERT INTO answers (id, value) 
VALUES(8, 3) 
ON CONFLICT (id) DO UPDATE SET value = EXCLUDED.value
WHERE answers.report_id = 55
```

The query works fine but the problem is that I have to assign `id` a unique value every time when there is no conflict and I don't know what the next best `id` is.

Another idea I have is to create a second column where I store another unique id for the answer and conflict check against that and keep the `id` as autoincrement.

A third idea I have is to first run a select question for a `question_id` for a particular `report`. If there is no such result run a regular insert, else update the existing one...

Ideally I would like to run a single query and not create a secondary unique answer id column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That sounds to me like you should create a unique constraint with two columns:

```
ALTER TABLE answers ADD UNIQUE (report_id, question_id);
```

Then you can use that constraint with `ON CONFLICT`:

```
INSERT INTO answers (question_id, report_id, value)
VALUES (1, 2, 'gewonnen')
ON CONFLICT (report_id, question_id) DO UPDATE
SET value = EXCLUDED.value;
```

Note that you don't need a `WHERE` clause, since this is only about the conflicting row anyway.

Also note that I did not specify `id`, so the autogenerated value is used.

Comment: Hello Albe, Your solution solved it. Thanks! I didn't know about the multi column constraint. I'll read up on that. I solved it earlier with two queries but this is way better. I bet the performance is also higher.